# How to make a Button at other Form

Tags: c#

I have 2 Forms add_Form and Form

If I click the button at the add_form
than I want to make the button at the Form

So I wrote this code but I can't make button

*I want to keep the created button even when the program is closed*

what line should edit?

```
        Form form = new Form();
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Location = new Point(70, 50);
        button.Text = "apple";
        button.Width = 100;
        form.Controls.Add(button);
        button.Show();
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing `form.Show();`

Comment: Re your edit: _"I want to keep the created button even when the program is closed"_ - If that's the case, you'll need to write code to save/load these dynamic components in a file (the format of that file to be determined by you and tailored to your requirements).

Comment: Your edit has kind of made what was one question into two. One sets out to solve the problem of _"So I wrote this code but I can't make button"_ and the other wants an answer to _"How do I make dynamically generated form components persist between application launches?"_. You should only ask one question at a time.

Comment: both. thanks to your solution i can make buttons but I need keep the buttons

Comment: Can you tag the specific technology you are using for this Button/Form if possible. I'm sure there's lots of C# libraries out there that provide such functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create your button at first by the normal way, and just set Visible to false or true as need